# Is it possible to remove specific tool from bokeh toolbar specially bokeh logo and help icon?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have been doing a small project on plotting graph for my school on bokeh but bokeh toolbar is coming with unnecessary logos.is it possible to remove specific tools? 
I have tried this but it's removing the entire toolbar

```
p.toolbar.logo = None
p.toolbar_location = None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to configure the toolbar to have only certain tools. So i rather add the tools that i want instead of removing them. And remove the logo:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models.tools import PanTool, SaveTool

p = figure()
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 4, 3, 0])
p.toolbar.logo = None
p.tools = [SaveTool(), PanTool()]
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

`p.toolbar_location = None` is specifically telling Bokeh not to display a toolbar anywhere. You only need the first line above.